# how to get a HTML span value that's dynamically changes overtime

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a DHT sensor and I used mqtt to send data to server. From there I displayed the data to a `span`, so the span value is changing.

What I want to do is: 
When sensor stop working, it will display fault in that `span` and I want to display image only when its fault.

```
<span id="fault"></span>
```

i tried to use JS to get the `span` then display image but its not working

```
<img src="yellowled.png" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="60" height="60" id="my_image">
    
<script>
    document.getElementById('my_image').style.display = 'none';
    var span_Text = document.getElementById("fault").innerText;
    if (span_Text  === "fault"){
       document.getElementById('my_image').style.display = 'inline';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: for me, your code is correct, when `<span id="fault">fault</span>` it shows the image, as expected

Comment: i tried that but the results shows empty string cause the sensor fault take some time to send the data

Comment: ah, then your problem is not what you think it is, you are not waiting the response, this is your problem. When sending data and waiting for response you need to await

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Where is the code that puts the fault message into the span? That's where you need to set the image to visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your span value is changing without refreshing the page, You need to trigger function on change value of span.

for that you need to make function:

```
function functionName(){
var span_Text = document.getElementById("fault").innerText;
    if (span_Text  === "fault"){
       document.getElementById('my_image').style.display = 'inline';
    }
}
```

Then you need to set Javascript [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) on your span id as `onchange` will not work for span.

Then you need to call your function when DOM changes.

```
var yourSpan = document.getElementById("fault");
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.info('changed');
    functionName();
  });    
});
 
var setting = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
 
observer.observe(yourSpan, setting);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

```
function callback (event) {
    // inspect event or event.target.textContent and react
}
observer = new MutationObserver((events) => events.forEach(callback));
observer.observe(document.getElementById("fault"), {childList: true, subtree: true, characterData: true});
```